# Loading data from .CSV file to an Oracle table using SQL developer 1,2

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement to load data from .CSV file to an Oracle production table(version 11.2) using Sql developer(1.2) where the file has 0.3 million records. When i tried to load using insert method it got hung and not able to proceed further.
Also,since it's an older version it doesn't have all the new features as well.
Do we have any other option to accomplish it?

Comment: ???Sql developer(1.2)??? That's 2007 ! Upgrade there's been plenty of updates in the last 11 years.

Comment: Yes Kris, our production team guy is having that version only and since we don't have the write privilege to run any script ,we are dependent on him.Also, we don't have enough time to upgrade it.

Comment: “Install” is just unzip so it’s quite trivial to do

Answer (score 0):

Each software tool has a specialization and strengths and weaknesses. The SQL developer is ideal for developing and testing SQL queries,stored procedures. The `sqlplus` is not suitable for development, it does not have a user-friendly interface, but it ideally executes very large scripts, it works very quickly.
To download a large amount of data is ideally suited specialized tool the SQL*loader(`sqlldr`). It does not have a graphical interface, you need to write a control script.